# Actionable messages via email is showing empty content in outlook

Tags: html, json, outlook, actionable-notification

I am using powershell script and smpt server to send email.

I am reading the html file from local path to send the actionable message for email.

Below is my html file:

```
<script type="application/adaptivecard+json">{
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "version":"1.0",
   "hideOriginalBody":true,
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"TextBlock",
         "text":"Visit the Outlook Dev Portal",
         "size":"large"
      },
      {
         "type":"TextBlock",
         "text":"Click **Learn More** to learn more about Actionable Messages!"
      },
      {
         "type":"Input.Text",
         "id":"feedbackText",
         "placeholder":"Let us know what you think about Actionable Messages"
      }
   ],
   "actions":[
      {
         "type":"Action.Http",
         "title":"Send Feedback",
         "method":"POST",
         "url":"https://...",
         "body":"{{feedbackText.value}}"
      },
      {
         "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
         "title":"Learn More",
         "url":"https://learn.microsoft.com/outlook/actionable-messages"
      }
   ]
}</script> 
Visit the Outlook Dev Portal to learn more about Actionable Messages.

reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email#feedback
```

only body tag part is visible in outlook not the json part.
Why the Json is not working?
What is the correct way to use this code?
What is file name i should use either filename.html or filename.Json?

JSON is working in codeplayground and not working if i save the filename as .html and .JSON.

Kindly guide me.

It would be grateful if someone help this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"The originator property must be set to a valid provider ID generated by the Actionable Email Developer Dashboard. Leaving this property empty when sending to others results in the card being removed."

If you just want to test the sender and the recipient has to be the same account.